# Does locally specifying an argument in a scope in tensorflow overwrite all following arguments of the same type?

Tags: arguments, tensorflow, padding, layer

I am currently trying to understand the inception-v3 architecture and was taking a closer look at the definition of the model's layers:

```
with scopes.arg_scope([ops.conv2d, ops.max_pool, ops.avg_pool],stride=1, padding=’VALID’):
    # 299 x 299 x 3
    end_points[’conv0’] = ops.conv2d(inputs, 32, [3, 3], stride=2,scope=’conv0’)
    # 149 x 149 x 32
    end_points[’conv1’] = ops.conv2d(end_points[’conv0’], 32, [3, 3], scope=’conv1’)
    # 147 x 147 x 32
    end_points[’conv2’] = ops.conv2d(end_points[’conv1’], 64, [3, 3], padding=’SAME’, scope=’conv2’)
    # 147 x 147 x 64
    end_points[’pool1’] = ops.max_pool(end_points[’conv2’], [3, 3], stride=2, scope=’pool1’)
    # 73 x 73 x 64
    end_points[’conv3’] = ops.conv2d(end_points[’pool1’], 80, [1, 1], scope=’conv3’)
    # 73 x 73 x 80.
    end_points[’conv4’] = ops.conv2d(end_points[’conv3’], 192, [3, 3], scope=’conv4’)
    # 71 x 71 x 192.
    end_points[’pool2’] = ops.max_pool(end_points[’conv4’], [3, 3], stride=2, scope=’pool2’)
    # 35 x 35 x 192.
    net = end_points[’pool2’]
```

Checking the dimensions of each layer, I first had to take a look at the different padding styles: `VALID` and `SAME`. `VALID` will discard edges, while `SAME` will actually pad equally on both sides, so convolution still works on edges.
This holds for example for the first layer with 299x299 pixels to 149x149 with a stride of 2, so we only consider all odd pixels [Filter size: [3,3]] and end up with a dimension of 149x149, not 150x150 because padding is `VALID` (edges are discarded). Convolving this layer again, with the same filter size but now a stride of 1 we get 147x147 due to the edges "suffering" from being discarded. This layer then is again convolved but now with the twist, that padding is set to `SAME` which results in the same dimension of 147x147 as the layer before.

Now comes the spot that confuses me:
Assuming, `SAME` padding was only valid for the `conv2` layer and is globally still set to `VALID`, the dimension for `pool1` is correctly shown as 73x73 due to discarding the edge. When now going to the next convolutional layer `conv3` I would expect it to become 71x71, taken the `VALID` padding as active. However, the output of `conv3` remains at 73x73, which means, that `SAME` padding is used. But in `conv4`, the padding now seems to be `VALID`, reducing the dimension to 71x71 confusing me totally.

In the readme on github of slim's `arg_scope` I found, that setting one of the arguments locally overrides the global argument given:

> ```
> with slim.arg_scope([slim.ops.conv2d], padding='SAME', stddev=0.01, weight_decay=0.0005):
>     net = slim.ops.conv2d(inputs, 64, [11, 11], scope='conv1')
>     net = slim.ops.conv2d(net, 128, [11, 11], padding='VALID', scope='conv2')
>     net = slim.ops.conv2d(net, 256, [11, 11], scope='conv3')
> ```
>
> As the example illustrates, the use of arg_scope makes the code
>   cleaner, simpler and easier to maintain. Notice that while argument
>   values are specifed in the arg_scope, they can be overwritten locally.
>   In particular, while the padding argument has been set to 'SAME', the
>   second convolution overrides it with the value of 'VALID'.

However, this would mean, that `conv4` should also have dimension of 73x73 because the padding would be `SAME`, so preserving the edges and the final pooling layer `pool2` would then even be 37x37.

What is the thing that I am missing? Where is my mistake?
Thank you for helping me, I hope I have made the confusing problem clear.

Comment: Not very useful, but the term is "convolve", not "convolute". :)

Comment: @chris_anderson thx, changed it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see the filter size for the `pool1` layer is actually `[1,1]` so it is not reducing the dimensions and has nothing to do with the `arg_scope` as it stays exactly how it should.